# Misplaced alignment tab character &. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}

Tags: symbols, alignment

Misplaced alignment tab character &. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}

```
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\label{bib:mybiblio}
\appendix
\input{sections/appAname.tex}
\end{document}
```

```
line 29: Misplaced alignment tab character &. ...raphy[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

i am getting this error and i can not find a entry in my bib file with a "&" that i havent allredy changed to "\&". can enyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344) to help us help you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's quite hard to tell with so little information. The error message should contain the line in which the error happened, which might give a clue on which entry contains the stray `&`. Give us more info to work on, please.

Comment: Note that errors like this can persist in the temporary files and may occur even if the source `.bib` is fixed. Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile from scratch. If the error persists, there is still an unescaped `&` in the `.bib`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer 2 was very helpful, the problem was that a had used a `&` instead of the word `and` in an author's name, I found it and correct it but it was until I erased the `.bbl` and `.blg` (both in my reference files and my main file, make a backup first) files then I have compiled with BibTeX then compile with pdflatex that the problem was corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in the .bib file, I foumd that I am using the & sign in the titles of the articles or in the journal name, I escaped it by using \ before the sign like below
`\&` ,
then the error disappeared